# Ошибка при инициализации поля

Tags: unity3d

Имею код:

```
public class Client : NetworkBehaviour
{
    public static Client Instance { get; private set; }
private void Awake() {
        Instance = this;
    }
}
```

К функциям из этого класса обращаюсь через Instance. Но не могу выполнить следующую функцию в другом классе:

```
public class sendMessage : NetworkBehaviour {

    Client networkTransmitter = GetComponent<Client>();
}
```

На GetComponent выдает ошибку:

> cannot access non-static method GetComponent in static context
>   Как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Назначение полю класса значения сразу после объявления считается его инициализацией.

Инициализаторы полей не могут использовать экземплярные методы, т.к. на момент их отработки экземпляра условно ещё не существует. В вашем случае стоит осуществлять назначение в методе Start или Awake

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вам static instance, если проще сделать без него ? т.к. в итоге это же не Singleton. Как я понял ты хочешь получить этот класс в тот же классе, но можно же его использовать и так.